# $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is a PID for $n=3,4,5$ using Minkowski theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I want to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is a PID for $n=3,4,5$ using Minkowski theory.

I know that if the class group is trivial, then it is a PID. Is this helpful to show the claim or how else can I proceed?

I'd be thankful for any help!

Comment: Have you ever proved some number field has class number $1$ using "Minkowski theory"? (I'd call it "geometry of numbers.") Certainly proving $h = 1$ is helpful, since it implies the ring is a PID as you explained.  Well, you need to show *also* that the ring of integers of ${\mathbf Q}(\zeta_n)$ is ${\mathbf Z}[\zeta_n]$ for $n = 3, 4, 5$. That formula for the ring of integers is also true for all larger $n$ as well, but the cyclotomic fields don't always have class number $1$ (e.g., when $n = 23$ we have $h = 3$).